# How much would a nine inch slice of the Earth's inner core weigh?

Tags: geophysics, core

If one took a slice of the Earth's inner core measuring nine inches across how much would that slice weigh? Or, conversely, how much mass would that contain?

Comment: I'm also confused by the very specific nature of this question.  Was this a homework question?  You'll find you're much more appreciate around here and get better answers if you explain why you have such a question, and probably add some input on what your thoughts are towards solving it.

Comment: Also explain just what you mean by a nine inch slice.  A sphere nine inches in diameter?  A cube nine inches on a side?  Or a slice through the core that's nine inches thick.

Answer (score 4):

An oddly specific question, but quite straightforward to calculate. Let's start by calculating the volume of your slice. I'm taking values for the inner core's physical characteristics from [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_of_the_Earth).

9 inches is ~0.229 m.
Radius of inner core: 1.21e6 m

We'll approximate your slice as a cylinder: even if we imagine the inner core is a textbook sphere down to the centimetre scale, its curvature would be miniscule over such a thin slice.

$\pi \times  (1.21 \times 10^6)^2 \times 0.229 \approx 1.05 \times 10^{12} \,\,\mathrm{m^3}$

So the volume of your slice is around a trillion cubic metres -- about one-fifth of a Lake Michigan, if Wikipedia is to be believed. Now we just need to turn this into a mass:

Density of inner core: 12800 kg/m³

$12800 \times 1.05 \times 10^{12} \approx 1.348 \times 10^{16}\,\,\mathrm{kg}$

So, roughly 13 trillion metric tonnes.

As jamesqf points out in a comment, this calculation just takes an estimated *average* density for the inner core, and assumes that this is the constant density throughout. In reality, the density increases with depth. Kennett (1998) gives a model for this density gradient.

[image: Earth density gradient]

The inner core is represented by the line section on the bottom right, below the horizontal discontinuity. Eyeballing the graph seems to imply a slightly higher average density than the estimate I pulled from Wikipedia (maybe around 1.3e4 kg/m³), varying by roughly 300 kg/m³ from the inner-core boundary to the centre. The Wikipedia estimate (for which they cite Hazeltt et al. (2006), p. 346) is actually 12,600–13,000 kg/m³ (I just took the mean for my calculation), so I suspect that uncertainties in the overall density values would swamp the inaccuracy introduced by my naïve, constant-density simplification. It's likely that a more reliable characterization of inner core density has been published since 2006; finding it and performing the requisite integration is left as an exercise for the reader ;-).

---

**References**

James S. Hazlett, Monroe, R. and Wicander, R. (2006). *Physical geology: exploring the Earth* (6. ed.). Belmont: Thomson. ISBN 9780495011484.

B. L. N. Kennett; On the density distribution within the Earth, Geophysical Journal International, Volume 132, Issue 2, 1 February 1998, Pages 374–382, https://doi.org/10.1046/j.1365-246x.1998.00451.x

Comment: @M.C.Nul I have a feeling that I've helped with either a homework question or a supervillain plot... but feel free to upvote and accept my answer if you feel it addressed your concerns adequately :).

Comment: Supervillian plot...Now! To Edward Muller's antimatter calculator! P.S. Mua! Hahaha!

Comment: But is density constant through the core?  I'd think not, due to pressure.  So you'd need to do an integral...

Comment: @jamesqf Good point. I've edited the question to address it.

Comment: In answer to James' question, a slice like a record or CD. In answer to the disquiet it seems I've sewn I'm writing a book in which the core gets sliced in two by a beam that creates antimatter at a distance...in the prologue. So...yeah, the fun part is undoing all the damage I gleefully cause at the very onset of the book.=D

Comment: About "Eyeballing the graph seems to imply a slightly higher average density than the estimate" points in the graph should be averaged according to the volume they represent. Since the core is a sphere, upper points represent a larger volume and therefore the average is displaced to those points, and Wikipedia estimate average doesn't seem contradictory at all.